# Embedding Facebook video in Phonegap Build App

Tags: facebook, video

I am building an app with phonegap build and simply want to display an embedded video that has been posted to a Facebook page. It works great in a web browser but will not display in the phonegap app. My config.xml file does contain

-access origin="*" />

Any idea how to get this to get a Facebook video to display in phonegap?

Comment: well, did you fix it?